# rsync huge folders

Tags: rsync

What's the optimal, smart parameters to rsync to achieve fastest checking of huge folders that rarely change and have lots of small files. I'm using the following command to sync a local disk to a USB3 disk at the end of each day (having done the opposite at the start of that day) and it still takes a minute even if there were no changes -- can one do the checks faster? For example, I thought each folder has a modification time, so no need recursively go into them if /Source/A and /Target/A have the same modified time? Or is it dangerous and rsync must check each of the nested thousand little files? Other ideas? Thanks

```
rsync -a --delete --stats /Source/ /Target/

Number of files: 208,645 (reg: 187,331, dir: 16,910, link: 4,404)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 11,103,192,078 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 65,536
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 4,126,114
Total bytes received: 17,677

sent 4,126,114 bytes  received 17,677 bytes  236,788.06 bytes/sec
total size is 11,103,192,078  speedup is 2,679.48
```

Comment: By default rsync do the best. https://www.mankier.com/1/rsync#-c https://serverfault.com/questions/211005/rsync-difference-between-checksum-and-ignore-times-options/211083#211083

Comment: folders only get modified time change if a file is create or removed within it, so every file's times need to be checked too.  you could use a tool like unison so the changes are written continuously to the usb disk, or you could use something like git, and use the usb driive as a repo to be pushed and pull to.

Comment: @roaima my source is a fixed NTFS and my portable USB3 backup stick carries ext4 at the moment...

Answer (score 2):

You'll not get much faster than that with `rsync` between two local devices, particularly where one of them is [non-native NTFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/718530/rsync-huge-folders?noredirect=1#comment1362460_718530). It's already trying to skip files that "look like" they are unchanged.

You might get a better throughput if you were transferring files between native filesystems (eg ext4) or two different systems, but probably not a lot.

There are no directory-based optimisations available, as every entry needs to be scanned to check if it's a directory, and modification times don't get propagated to parents.